# ReactiveRedisTemplate opsForValue().set not working

Tags: java, kotlin, redis, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am trying to save oauth login credentials in redis . Using spring oauth2 library, and spring redis.

My saveAuthorizedClient method should be saving the key/val pair in redis, but nothing is being saved. Have attached a debugger and the key value pairs are correctly assigned, its the **reactiveOauthRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, authorizedClient)** which seems to be not doing anything.

```
class CustomClientService(
        val reactiveClientRegistrationRepository: ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository,
        val reactiveOauthRedisTemplate: ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClient>
) : ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService {


    override fun <T : OAuth2AuthorizedClient> loadAuthorizedClient(clientRegistrationId: String, principalName: String): Mono<T> {
        Assert.hasText(clientRegistrationId, "clientRegistrationId cannot be empty")
        Assert.hasText(principalName, "principalName cannot be empty")
        return clientRegistrationRepository.findByRegistrationId(clientRegistrationId)
                .map { rediskey(clientRegistrationId, principalName) }
                .flatMap { key: String ->
                    reactiveOauthRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key) as Mono<T>
                }
    }

    override fun saveAuthorizedClient(authorizedClient: OAuth2AuthorizedClient, principal: Authentication): Mono<Void> {
        val key = rediskey(authorizedClient.clientRegistration.registrationId, principal.name)
        reactiveOauthRedisTemplate.opsForValue().set(key, authorizedClient)
                .let {
                    val x = reactiveOauthRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key)
                    println("my redis data is $x")
                    x.map {
                        println("my data value is $it")
                        val token = x as OAuth2AuthorizedClient
                    }
                }

        return Mono.empty()
    }

    private fun rediskey(clientRegistrationId: String, principalName: String): String {
        return "something..."
    }
}
```

Here's my redis config

```
@Configuration
class RedisConfig {
    @Bean
    fun reactiveOauthRedisTemplate(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory: ReactiveRedisConnectionFactory,
                                   resourceLoader: ResourceLoader): ReactiveRedisTemplate<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClient> {
        val keySerializer: RedisSerializer<String> = StringRedisSerializer()
        val defaultSerializer = JdkSerializationRedisSerializer(resourceLoader.classLoader)
        val serializationContext = RedisSerializationContext
                .newSerializationContext<String, OAuth2AuthorizedClient>(defaultSerializer).key(keySerializer).hashKey(keySerializer)
                .build()
        return ReactiveRedisTemplate(reactiveRedisConnectionFactory, serializationContext)
    }
}
```

redis yaml config

```
spring:
  redis:
    host: localhost
```

From debugger , the redis connect has host and port correct.  Any help here is appreciated.

Here's my redis client object from debugger

```
redisURI = {RedisURI@12018} "redis://127.0.0.1"
 host = "127.0.0.1"
 socket = null
 sentinelMasterId = null
 port = 6379
 database = 0
 clientName = null
 username = null
 password = null
 ssl = false
 verifyMode = {SslVerifyMode@12033} "FULL"
 startTls = false
 timeout = {Duration@12010} "PT1M"
 sentinels = {ArrayList@12034}  size = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of react client is not correct, you should not return `Mono.empty()` from `saveAuthorizedClient`, you should return `Mono<Boolean>`  and subscribe to it. You can ignore the return value if you do not need the result, but you must subscribe it so that it will execute the business logic.